# gapi-google-analytics-php-interface total number of records varying from time to time

Tags: google-api-js-client

I have made call to Google analtics  API using https://github.com/erebusnz/gapi-google-analytics-php-interface  and number of records i get on each call vary from time to time . Say in first call i get 800 records after some time i get 500 total records. I have not made any changes to parameters.Value each page is showing correct but count of some items are missing.

Am using example.report.php with my key and email .

Thanks
Jithin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oho , I found the answer after a long time. i was calculating from 2005 Jan 1st.Everything works fine on calculating with reference to date of google analytics implementation on my site